# jQuery : A simple tag replacement

Tags: jquery, tags, replace

I just want to replace all `<p>` tags with `<tr>`

```
function test() {
$("p").each(function(index) {
var htmlStr = $(this).html();
$(this).replaceWith("<tr>" + htmlStr + "<\/tr>");
});
}
```

It's not working. the replacement does work but the html content of the `<p>` tags is removed. so the output would be something like `<tr></tr>`

Also, this function will go through all the entire html page, right ? I just want it to be processed on my `#content_div`. Is there anything I should add or before `$("p")` ?

Comment: In all fairness, those other questions don't have "correct" answers yet. Mostly because 2 of them are vague and ambiguous. But I have added a comment to the one that "could" be answered. His questions seem to be getting better ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `<TR>` can't contain anything other than `<TH>` or `<TD>`. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RUHG5/2/)

```
function test() {
    $("#content_div").find('p').each(function(index) {
        var htmlStr = $(this).html();
        $(this).replaceWith("<tr><td>" + htmlStr + "</td><\/tr>");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry I couldn't figure out the problem myself.

Comment: I don't know why but the code is not working in IE (9). I am trying to figure out... It does work with FF.

Comment: That isolated example works in IE9, but used in a page it may not do what you want, since it is a very very bad idea to make tables this way.  When a modern browser sees table elements (TR TD) just floating around like this it will build a table around it. This process may be interfering with something on your page. The best idea is to give us some context of what you're trying to do here, as there is probably a much safer way to get it done.

Comment: What content is being brought in? Right now you just have an empty table inside of a div. What is this function being asked to parse from  fetch.php?

Comment: The content that is pulled is something like `<p>First File<a href="blab.mp3">blab</a></p>` What function are you referring to ? BTW, I tried another way to solve this (using wraps) but still again the problem resist in IE. I think IE's problem is `.replaceWith` here is it : http://jsfiddle.net/vK9zL/2/

Comment: You can't put <p>s in tables, any browser will force the content out first. I think this project really needs to go back to the drawing board. Decide what information you have access to, how you're going to store it, and what you'd like to do with it. Any time you work with invalid html the results will be unpredictable at best.

Comment: No I think you got it wrong. Look, the above code is the ajax response that is fetched from wordpress. I just want to get rid of `<p>` tags, wrap it up with `<tr>`, then put the rest of text and anchor in `<td>`. So after doing these, the final code should be `<tr><td>First File</td><td><a href="blab.mp3">blab</a></td></tr>`

Comment: Yes, but but the bigger question would be WHY you feel that you need to change <p> tags into table rows. I'm not saying it's wrong, just that it might not be the best approach. As it stands now, none of the jsFiddles you have created are doing ANYTHING since you have left them set to MooTools instead of having them load jQuery (the dropdown menue on the left panel), so all you are seeing the different behaviours of each of the browsers with your invalid html. I would recommend using firebug/chrome-inspector/developer-tools for firefox/chrome/IE to help you debug your markup and javascript. GL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5944/discussion-between-sinetheta-and-xperator)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing no content because you are creating content in a tr tag as an example here http://jsfiddle.net/Pf5n3/

For the content to show you will need to have your content in a td if you are not allready in a tr like this
http://jsfiddle.net/Pf5n3/1/

Comment: my second example is the same as @Sinethea

Answer (score 0):

it's unreliable to manipulate HTML directly via search/replace functions - any attributes in the HTML being parsed would break the code..

i'd chose to do it this way.. given any empty target table of

```
<table>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

use this javascript

```
function test() {
    $("p").each(function(index) {
        $("tbody").append($("<tr></tr>").html(this.innerHTML));
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

[see the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/8Mbpx/)

Comment: Why the Div? Now you've got a tbody with divs in it.

Comment: the OP could append the TR rows to whichever element he/she chose, i just gave an example.. never-the-less, i edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimenting, and figured you could use the wrap function of jQuery to add a tag around an element. This would leave the paragraph tags in place, but that is probably not your main concern. This results in some very easy to follow code:

```
$("#content_div p").wrap("<tr>");
```

However, this makes no sense as noted in the other posts as you probably also need a TD tag as well and possibly a table tag around all the elements. Your code would then look like this:

```
$("#content_div p").wrapAll("<table>");
$("#content_div p").wrap("<tr><td>");
```