# Symfony 1.4 and Bootstrap. How I can format a list of checkboxes as does Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, symfony-1.4

I work with Symfony 1.4 and Bootstrap. I have a problem formatting list of checkboxes. The text of each checkboxes appears with a line break regarding its checkbox.

Symfony generates this HTML code to each checkbox:

```
<li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="5" id="mensajes_receptores_list_5" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_5">Carlos (Admin)</label></li>
```

For Bootstrap display correctly each checkboxes, I need Symfony generate the following code:

```
<label class="checkbox">
 <input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="5" id="mensajes_receptores_list_5" /> Carlos (Admin)
</label>
```

How I can get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the approach to solve the problem and decided to use jQuery. I proceeded to create

```
<div id="checkbox_emisores">
```

Then en _form.php would look like this:

```
<div id="checkbox_emisores">
          <?php echo $form['receptores_list']->renderError() ?>
          <?php echo $form['receptores_list'] ?>
 </div>
```

Here the function to replace tags for checkboxes generated by Symfony 1.4 by the tag you need Bootstrap.
I adapted the function as shown here:

[jQuery : A simple tag replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546453/jquery-a-simple-tag-replacement)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false       
    });
// First delete the label generated by symfony
  $("#checkbox_emisores").find('label').each(function(index) {
 var htmlStr = $(this).html();
 $(this).replaceWith(htmlStr);
 });  
//Then replace the symfony <li> with <label generated class='checkbox'> as needed in Bootstrap 
  $("#checkbox_emisores").find('li').each(function(index) {
var htmlStr = $(this).html();
$(this).replaceWith("<label class='checkbox'>"+htmlStr+"</label>");
});   
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

On your form class:

```
$this->widgetSchema['receptores_list']->setAttribute('class', 'checkbox');
```

And try to configure form decorators (sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter)

Comment: The option 'setAttribute ('class', 'checkbox')' does not work as I need. Symfony places the attribute for the set, but not for each checkbox as I need. I'm trying to 'sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter' but neither achieved the desired result.